# MacOS Safari having different app and website language

Tags: macos, safari

My preferred language is Danish, but I prefer having my MacOS system language set to English but I have set country as region.

[image: Language & Region settings]

That's works perfectly, but in Safari some webpages is by default displaying pages in English, where I would prefer my local language (Dansk). Here is what JavaScript's `navigator.language` in Safari tells the website about me.

[image: JavaScript navigator.language]

Is it possible to override the preferred website language in MacOS Safari without changing the entire App language to Danish? Other browsers like Firefox and Chrome has options for that, but I cannot find anything in Safari.